# AWS Workspace wont launch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-workspaces

I tried launching an AWS Workspace and it is stuck launching.

AWS says it may take up to 20 minutes to launch but it has been hours.

I looked at their documentation and it mentions that I can take a look at the directories tab in the Workspce console. And I should see the related directory - create in progress, but alas, I don't even see this.

Any one have any ideas on what going on?

[image]

Comment: Try solutions on https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/workspaces-stuck-status/#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20still%20experiencing,will%20change%20within%2090%20minutes.

Comment: I notice in your picture that is says "1 to 1", which suggests that there _is_ something being listed but you can't see it. Check whether there is a window pane that you can move -- it might be hiding the WorkSpace information! You can verify this by using the AWS CLI to run `aws workspaces describe-workspaces`

Comment: Did not notice the 1, but checked on the AWS CLI got:

{
    "Workspaces": []
}

So, weirdly enough its empty.

I also cheeked the console again, nothing is showing up.